# File upload using Web API

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web, asp.net-web-api, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to implement file upload (excel files) using,

```
Visual Studio 2012,
ASP.NET Web Forms,
jquery,
Web API
Browser: IE 8
```

I tried to follow online examples but they were using FormData and it is not working for me.

```
$('#ImportFileBtn').on('click', function () {

        var fileName = $('#ImportFileSelection').val();

        var data = "<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'><body><input type='file' id='facilityFile' value='"+fileName +"' /></body></form>"

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "api/Import/ProcessImport",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (messages) {
                alert('ok');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error while invoking the Web API");
            }
        });
    });
```

Please suggest me how to upload an excel file to Web API controller with the above tools and technology.

Thanks,
Vim

Comment: Why degrade mark? Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that IE8/9 do not know about FormData. There are several jQuery plug-ins you can use to work around this problem. Here are some libraries you could use (not a complete list):

- [jQuery Form Plugin](https://github.com/malsup/form)
- [drogus/jquery-upload-progress](https://github.com/drogus/jquery-upload-progress)
- [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)
- ... (more can be found through Google)

This is not a perfect option, but a plugin will make some things easier. Some of them need a lot of extra code. If you just need this functionality, choose one that integrates into jQuery's ajax method (have done this in a project some time ago, but can't remember the name of the library I used).

**UPDATE**

Just for the records: The library I used is called [jQuery iFrame-Transport](http://cmlenz.github.io/jquery-iframe-transport/), because I had to support very old versions of IE.

Comment: Thank you. I will try the above plugins and keep you updated.

Comment: I am proceeding with jQuery File Upload plugin.

Answer (score -2):

Web API is for allowing other applications to consume data from it. You cannot upload files there.

Comment: That's not true. You can upload files to the server or a storage system (such as Azure Blob Storage) via Web API. For an example have a look at [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806075/File-Upload-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASP-NET-Web-API).